# react native Error: Command failed: ./gradlew build -x lint

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am running my react native project using `react-native run-android --deviceId=<ID>` and got this error

> BUILD FAILED in 43s
> 161 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 141 up-to-date
> error Failed to build the app.
> Error: Command failed: ./gradlew build -x lint
> at makeError (/Users/Julian/Desktop/Projects/TestApp/mobileclient/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
> at Function.module.exports.sync (/Users/Julian/Desktop/Projects/TestApp/mobileclient/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:338:15)
> at buildApk (/Users/Julian/Desktop/Projects/TestApp/mobileclient/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:181:22)
> at runOnSpecificDevice (/Users/Julian/Desktop/Projects/TestApp/mobileclient/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:162:7)
> at buildAndRun (/Users/Julian/Desktop/Projects/TestApp/mobileclient/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:147:12)
> at /Users/Julian/Desktop/Projects/TestApp/mobileclient/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:132:12
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (/Users/Julian/Desktop/Projects/TestApp/mobileclient/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)

I have tried to

```
npm uninstall react-native-cli
reinstall my node version and npm version

react version: 0.65.1
node version: v14.21.3
npm version: 6.14.18
```

Nothing works. Any solution? Many Thanks!